# TypeError: invalid 'in' operand a error when calling jQuery each inside RequireJS module

Tags: javascript, jquery, gruntjs, requirejs, amcharts

I have the following RequireJS module which I am using to build a chart with AmCharts. (I have removed some code for brevity).

```
define('admin/stats', ['jquery', 'amcharts.serial'], function($, AmCharts) {

    var historicalStats = {

        init: function(rawData, axesMarker) {

            var originalData = rawData,
            charts = $('#charts');

            console.log(originalData);

            $.each(originalData, function(graphName, config) {
                // ...call a function in here...
            });

        }

    };

    return historicalStats;

});
```

This is how I am calling it:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    require(['admin/stats'], function(stats) {
        stats.init('{{ data|raw }}', '{{ "graphs.axes.filesize"|trans({}, "admin") }}');
    });

</script>
```

The problem I have is the line `$.each(originalData, function(graphName, config) {` errors with the following:

> TypeError: invalid 'in' operand a
>   ...w:this,function(a,b){function
>   c(a){var b="length"in a&&a.length,c=_.type(a);retu...

(I am using `grunt` to minify the JavaScript).

`originalData` looks like this:

> {"users":{"series":[{"field":"users","title":"Users"}],"type":"raw","axesMarker":"Users","data":[]},"fileusage":{"type":"filesize","axesMarker":"File
>   size","series":[],"data":[]},"dbsize":{"series":[{"field":"dbsize","title":"Database
>   size"}],"type":"filesize","axesMarker":"File size","data":[]}}

I have traced the error back to that individual line by commenting out everything else. What is it about that line that is incorrect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this call:

```
stats.init('{{ data|raw }}', '{{ "graphs.axes.filesize"|trans({}, "admin") }}');
```

you pass a string as the first argument. And then `$.each` tries to look for `"length"` in this string: `"length" in a` (where `a` is initialized to the same value as the first argument passed to `stats.init`.

If `{{ data|raw }}` is a correctly formatted JavaScript object or JSON you could drop the quotes. However, I'm concerned about how you copy `rawData` to `originalData` in your code. If you just remove the quotes and get a JavaScript object, know that if you modify `originalData` in your later code then *`rawData` will also have the same modifications* because you are not cloning it. So if you want to isolate it from changes to `originalData`, you'd have to clone it. (There are many ways to clone, which is best in your case depends on details that are not in your question.)

Another possibility would be to leave the call to `stats.init` as-is, but inside the function do:

```
var originalData = JSON.parse(rawData)
```

This assumes that `{{ data|raw }}` is correctly formatted JSON.

Comment: Dropping the `'` around `'{{ data|raw }}'` was the solution. Thank you.